# Add link to methods to array in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a index method in my rails 4 application controller that looks like:

```
def index
   @products = Product.all
   @headers = @products.map(&:data).flat_map(&:keys).uniq
   @product_data = @products.map{ |product| product[ :data ].values }
end
```

So @product_data ends up with something like:

```
[["Table", "$199.99", "blue"], ["Book", "$9.99", "green"]]
```

In my view, I put all of this in a unordered list. But now I'd like to have a link_to an edit and delete page for each product. How can I include this in my array, so I can display a link for each product on the view page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `product_id` to the result of `product[:data].values` array.  Then use that `product_id` as parameter to your `product` `url_helpers`.

```
@product_data = products.map{ |product| product[ :data ].values.unshift(product.id) }
```

This should give you something similar to:

```
[[1, "Table", "$199.99", "blue"], [2, "Book", "$9.99", "green"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I see there is no use of `@product_data` there.Why can't You display the data in a table in your `index.html.erb` and you can loop through every product,so that the **edit** and **delete** links appear to every product.Assuming that you have `name`,`price` and `color` attributes for your product model,just do like this

**In your index.html.erb:**

```
<table border=1>

    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Product Price</th>
        <th>Product Color</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
        <% @products.each do |p| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%=p.name %></td>
        <td><%=p.price %></td>
        <td><%=p.color %></td>
        <td><%=link_to 'Edit', :action => "edit", :id => p.id %></td>
        <td><%=link_to 'Delete', :action => "delete", :id => p.id, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %></td>
    </tr>
     <% end %>
</table>
```

**Note:**
Its just an another approach.